# Chinese characters as dictionary KEY

Tags: python

I am trying to create a dictionary lookup variable like this:

```
lookup = {
    u'安徽省':'Anhui',
    u'福建省':'Fujian',
    u'甘肃省':'Gansu',
    u'广东省':'Guangdong',
    u'贵州省':'Guizhou',
    u'浙江省':'Zhejiang'
}
```

I am calling an API and it returns the result in Chinese. I want to simply have a look up table to convert it to the English name.

So my code is:

```
api_response = api.geocode(address, isChina)
if len(api_response['Response']['View']) > 0:
        state = lookup[api_response['Response']['View'][0]['Result'][0]['Location']['Address']['State']]
```

But the error I get is:

```
2019-07-29 15:35:13.193 | ERROR    | __main__:<module>:148 - Traceback (most recent call last):   File "format.py", line 93, in <module>
    new_dict = doStepByStepCleanse(row, isChina, line_count)   File "format.py", line 43, in doStepByStepCleanse
    state =  lookup[api_response['Response']['View'][0]['Result'][0]['Location']['Address']['State']] KeyError: '山东省'
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: I don't see `山东省` in your dictionary

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: A `dict` key can be any hashable value. A `str` (or `unicode` string if using Python 2.7) is hashable so there is nothing special about Chinese characters. However what @cricket_007 has stated is likely your issue.

Comment: I am using Python 3.7. @cricket_007 answer is correct! The key was not there. To be honest I look at this chinese characters and they all look the same to me.
THanks cricket!

Comment: If you are using python3.7 you don't need to use `u'text'` as all is` unicode` by default.

Comment: @Rahul is correct. Then again, it's a good practice to use ```u'string'``` to avoid code transfusion errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the error, I'm not sure you've defined all possible keys that the API returns. There's nothing special about the Chinese characters being in the dictionary, just that `KeyError: '山东省'` means that it really isn't there in your dictionary

If you're not guaranteed to have all known keys ahead of time, you should fallback to getting a default value

```
lookup.get(api_response['Response']['View'][0]['Result'][0]['Location']['Address']['State']], "Unknown")
```